# Toad for Oracle - save multiple editor sheets with queries to a single file

Tags: oracle, toad

I am wondering if there is a feature that allows you to save multiple sheets with sql queries into a single file that could be reused many times.

I would like to organise my SQL queries in a multiple sheets and save them to a single file. When I would reopen this file, multiple sheets should be displayed with my SQL statements. At this moment  I have to save each sheet as a separate file and it's a bit annoying... can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you'd want to use the **Workspaces** feature.

> You can save your current Toad windows and connections as a Workspace. This allows you to quickly resume work after restarting Toad.
>
> If you don't see the Workspace toolbar, right-click in the main toolbar to select "Workspaces" (...)
>
> These components are saved:
>
> - (...) Editor - the tab contents, the number of tabs, the last active tab, each tab's line and caret position, and the split mode of the Editor (...)